# backup the database using MySql

Tags: mysql

hi i want to backup my MySql database,
i write this command :

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword -h localhost --all-databases > backup.sql;
```

and it give this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
dump -u root -pmanager -h localhost --all-databases > backup.sql' at line 1
```

why?
and what should be do?
thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running this command in mysql. You should be running it from the command line instead.

Comment: it give me: Access is denied.
why?

Comment: is there a command or a way to know the open sessions in mysq?

Comment: @ooo `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` will list open sessions.